# nested dataIndex in Table of Ant Design

Tags: antd

this is my code below

```
const columns =  [
    {
          key: '1',
          title: 'id',
          dataIndex: 'id'
    },
    {
          key: '2',
          title: 'status',
          dataIndex: 'status',
          render: (text) => <a> {text} </a>
     },
];
```

I wanna display data  ( text/id ) like below code

```
 const columns =  [
    {
          key: '1',
          title: 'id',
          dataIndex: 'id'
    },
    {
          key: '2',
          title: 'status',
          dataIndex: ['status', 'id'],
          render: (text) => <a> {text} / {id} </a>
     },
];
```

I tried to like this samples

```
1. dataIndex: ['status', 'id']
2. dataIndex: 'status.id'
```

but that doesn`t work.  (version 4.14.0)
how can I display like that? please reply here. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
{
   title: "Task",
   dataIndex: ["task","name"]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer assuming what you pass to the `dataSource` is an array of objects which looks like below.

```
interface DataModel {
  id: number;
  status: string;
}
```

If so, you can use the second parameter in the `render` method which will have the record. Hence `record.id` will give you the id.

```
 const columns =  [
    {
          key: '1',
          title: 'id',
          dataIndex: 'id'
    },
    {
          key: '2',
          title: 'status',
          dataIndex: ['status'],
          render: (text: any, record: any) => <a> {text} / {record.id} </a>
     },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
 {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    key: 'name',
    render: ({ city, street }) => (
      <Typography>{`${city} ${street}`}</Typography>
    ),
  },
```